# From jar, call java file thats outside jar

Tags: java, jar

So I have a `jared` java program that runs via a batch file. However it will need to be maintained and I don't want to have to create a new `jar` file every time. I want to put the java file that will be modified outside the `jar`, and have the `jar` file call it. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Do you mean `.java` or `.class`? It makes a big difference.

Comment: Do you mean a file inside another jar?

Comment: If it is a `.java` file it would need to be compiled first.

Comment: @735Tesla `.java` needs to be compiled first, not `.class`.

Comment: @RyanCarlson sorry I am a bit off today. Christmas break just ended and I am tired.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Most will create the jar for you. Any `.java` file will need to be compiled after being edited. I do not think there is a way to have them compiled at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the classpath to include the jar and the (compiled) Java file. You'd have to specify the main class in your batch file as well.